# @PreUpdate is getting called during fetch operation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have upgraded the spring-boot application from **1.5.10** to **2.2.2**.

I have one method which gets called on the login page before a user is authenticated. So that method is marked as `permitAll()` in the security configuration. This method calls `userRepository` to fetch data from db.

JPA code looks as below:

```
@Query("SELECT t2 FROM table t1 INNER JOIN  t1.table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = :param1 and t2.id = :param2")
SomeEntity getsomedata(@Param("param1") long param1, @Param("param2") long param2);
```

Each entity is audited. The method is only fetching data and not updating any entity.
Still, `@PreUpdate` method is being called. In `@PreUpdate` method , we are taking the authenticated user to log some info to audit tables. So call to fetch db data is getting failed, as the user is not authenticated.

Why `@PreUpdate` is getting called as we are not updating any data?

This was working in spring boot **1.5.10** version

Does fetching data using @Query calls flush() method?

As I can see logs after get call flush method is being called.

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.EntityCallback.performCallback(EntityCallback.java:32)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:71)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:332)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:283)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:154)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:235)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:94)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1415)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1501)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1553)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Are you really not updating data? As soon as you are calling a setter you are modifying data, might even be that something else is calling the setter without you knowing it (like setting a date for last logon etc.).

Comment: @M.Deinum no i am not updating any data....it was working in spring-boot 1.5.10.Code is same...version is upgraded...only made required changes to be compatible with new version i.e. 2.2.2

Comment: Something must be updating the user else it won't get called.

Comment: @M.Deinum same code was working with spring-boot 1.5.10...are there any changes in spring security in new release  which updates user?